# MVC Bootstrap 4: .col-md-2 wrong rendering - _grid-framework.scss appear twice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to migrate my old mvc app to bootstrap 4 and admitedly I have little experience with scss files.

Lets say I have a simple _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Source/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Source/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script src="~/Source/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Source/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

a View:

```
<div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            -OOO-
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            -WWW-
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            -KKK-
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and a Controller with method:

```
public ActionResult Index() => View();
```

> Bootstrap v4.3.1
>
> JQuery v3.4.1

As soon as the View renders the weird situation happens, the '.col-md-2' class is rendered with wrong width values because '_grid-framework.scss' appear twice in the styles list and the wrong one has precedence:

[image: bootstrap4-wrongrender]

My questions are:

1. Why browsers see two different files with the same path??
2. How do I make bootstrap generate only the correct version of the file?

I tried the regular things with clearing cache, clearing/recompiling, removing content from the IIS and rebooting the IIS.

**// EDIT 1**

Actually the comment about bootrap 4 dropping `.col-sm-*`, `.col-md-*`, etc confused me and it turns out [it is not really the case](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) (they even added [xl](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-bootstrap4/) tier). So the problem stands, I am currently overriding `.col-md-2` styling in the `.css` file but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 the xs-, sm-, md-, lg- parts have been dropped. Now you just use col-X (where X is the number of columns you want, for any size). So instead of col-sm-4 it is now col-4

Comment: If I replace `.col-md-*` with `.col-<any_other_size>-*` including `.col-*` it won't bug. As for the dropped keywords please see `// EDIT 1` section in my post